# Why I'm getting "Object.defineProperty called on non-object" when using a binded function as 1st parameter in Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, prototype, ecmascript-5, defineproperty

I'm trying to bind the this keyword of a function and use the Function as with object dot notation (as Functions are also objects).
I figured out using the object literal 'get' to do something like: myFunction.whatever (instead of myFunction().whatever).

Code is:

```
let template = {name: "William"};
let aux = function(){}
callTo = aux.bind(template);

Object.defineProperty(callTo.prototype, "scream", {
    get: function() {
        console.log(this);
        return "Hi, " + this.name;
    }
});
myObj = new callTo();
myObj.scream;
```

This causes the: "*Object.defineProperty called on non-object*" error
However, if I bind in each property defined with "get" it will correctly work.

```
let template = {name: "William"};
let callTo = function(){}

Object.defineProperty(callTo.prototype, "scream", {
    get: function() {
        console.log(this);
        return "Hi, " + this.name;
    }.bind(template)
});
myObj = new callTo();
myObj.scream;  // Outputs Hi William
```

The working approach  works but obligues me to add a bind() at the end of each propery. So question is:

**¿Why is first code failing?**

Comment: `callTo.prototype` is `undefined`. I'm not even sure why you'd attempt to change it here, though - seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Wait, why would you add properties to the prototype *and bind them*? If you just want methods that have immutable `this`, there are other approaches.

Comment: Reviewing the code again, I'm not even sure what the intention here is.

Comment: @VLAZ I used prototype here because I borrowed that approach from someone else's code, while I was experimenting with defineProperty in conjuntion with getters to call a function without the parenthesis.
Originally (before using defineProperty) I had a reveal-pattern code:  `callTo = function() { return {scream: this.xxxxx}}.bind(template)`, but that made me access 'scream' as callTo().scream (notice parenthesis)

Comment: `callTo = (function() { return {scream: this.xxxxx}}.bind(template))()` would allow you to do `callTo.scream` if that's what you wish. Although if you need this multiple times I'd probably do something more like `makeCall = function(template) { return { scream: template.xxxx  } }` and then you'd reuse it as `callTo = makeCall(template)`. With a module pattern you can also declare `self = template` and use `self` (or whatever name you choose) instead of `this` in methods. I don't see *what* you're trying to accomplish here. It seems like the Y is too complex but I don't know what the X is.